# ajuda aqui div e funçoes html

Tags: html, funções, div, button

Eu tenho esse código, quando eu passo o mouse sobre a div ele move, mas eu queria que isso acontecesse quando eu apertar no botão:

```
<head>
<style>
    .square{width:100px ;height:100px ;background:red ;transition: all 2s;}

  .square:hover{background:blue;-webkit-transform:translateX(40px);}

 </style>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<title>JS Bin</title>

</head>

<body>

<button id="moveRight"> Move Right</button>

<div class="square"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

A forma mais direta para fazer isso é atribuir uma classe com o mesmo estilo que tem no `hover`, e aplica-la quando clica no botão.

Para fazer com que a mesma volte para trás após os dois segundos temos a função [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout). Quando esta função de tempo corre é necessário voltar a remover a classe para restaurar o estado original do quadrado:

```js
const quadrado = document.querySelector(".square");

document.getElementById("moveRight").addEventListener("click", function(){
  quadrado.classList.add("mover");//adicionar a classe mover no click
  
  //agora após 2 segundos remove a classe mover que tinha sido adicionada
  setTimeout(() => quadrado.classList.remove("mover"), 2000); 
});
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .square {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: red;
      transition: all 2s;
    }
    
    .square:hover, .mover {
      background: blue;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(40px);
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="moveRight"> Move Right</button>
  <div class="square"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Documentação para a propriedade `classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) que tem os métodos `add` e `remove` utilizados

Comment: apaga a primeira resposta

Comment: @zasalamelcorrey Referes-te ao primeiro exemplo é isso ? Não era o que pretendias ?

Comment: o segundo ja serviu, apaga o primeiro

Comment: ficou repetitivo

Comment: @zasalamelcorrey Ok já removi, vê se ficou mais fácil para perceberes.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma classe que irá mover a `div`.

No exemplo abaixo, substituí a *pseudo-classe* `.square:hover` pela classe `.mover`, que será adicionada à `div` ao clique do botão, fazendo-a mover-se:

```js
document.getElementById("moveRight").onclick = function(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("square")[0].className += " mover";
};
```

```css
.square{width:100px ;height:100px ;background:red ;transition: all 2s;}
.mover{background:blue;-webkit-transform:translateX(40px);}
```

```html
<button id="moveRight"> Move Right</button>
<div class="square"></div>
```